# How to prevent PDFBox 1.8's print to leave a margin on the top of printed document?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I use PDFBox (1.8.12) to print pdf documents from java :

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0]));
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); // <<< supposedly prints in A4 format
attr_set.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

PDPageable p = new PDPageable(pdf);


job.setPageable(p);

PrintService ps = null;
for  (PrintService i : PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,null)) {
    if (i.getName().equals(args[1])) {
        ps = i;
    }
}

if (ps == null) {
    try {
        throw new SystemException(ErrorCode.NO_PRINTER_FOUND);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else
{

    job.setPrintService(ps);
    job.print(attr_set);

}
```

The problem is, the printed document has a margin which is cut, and I don't know why. I ran tests, to loop the pdf back into the pdf virtual printer, the seem to be the same, which, I think, means that PDFbox does not process the pdf in a wrong manner.

After further researches, the text on the printed paper seems like magnified, it begins higher, and finishes lower than the original (when I directly print from the concrete printer).

The paper on which I print is A4 format, so i tried to set the format to A4 like I did above, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution :

```
PDFPageable p = new PDFPageable(pdf);
PDFPrintable printable = new PDFPrintable(pdf,Scaling.SCALE_TO_FIT);

job.setPageable(p);
job.setPrintable(printable);
```

to apply the right format. I will edit if I must remove it but for now, I'll just post the whole thing on github : 
[GPierre-Antoine:Print_A4_APACHE_PDFBOX)](https://github.com/GPierre-Antoine/Print_A4_APACHE_PDFBOX/)

If I made a mistake, feel free to fork / comment / help.

Here I did an extract of said code:

```
package com.pierreantoineguillaume;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrintable;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.Scaling;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class BasicPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicPrinter basicPrinter = new BasicPrinter();
        String printerName = "name of my printer";
        String filename = "my file to print";

        try {
            Optional<PrintService> printService = basicPrinter.getMatchingPrintService(printerName);
            basicPrinter.printA4(printService.get(), PDDocument.load(new File(filename)));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not locate printer " + printerName);
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not print file because some error occurred during the print job or a compatibility error with the service");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not find file to print");
        }
    }

    public void printA4(PrintService printer, PDDocument documentToPrint) throws PrinterException {

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(documentToPrint));
        job.setPrintable(new PDFPrintable(documentToPrint, Scaling.SCALE_TO_FIT));


        job.setPrintService(printer);
        job.print(getA4Attributes());
    }

    public Optional<PrintService> getMatchingPrintService(String printerName) {
        for (PrintService i : PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, getA4Attributes())) {
            if (i.getName().equals(printerName)) {
                return Optional.of(i);
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private PrintRequestAttributeSet getA4Attributes() {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        return attr_set;
    }
}
```